# Firebase Catch Exceptions + List of Firebase Exceptions Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, exception, firebase-authentication

**Im using Firebase Email and Password Auth** to login to my App
I made a simple login form and register form as usual

**My Problem** is I dont know how to handle with exceptions...
There is this Log where I can see if e.g. the Email is in a bad format.

*But I want that if an error occurs i catch it and print it out*, a specific test for normal exceptions like email wrong, password wrong etc

Also I ask my self, if there is a list of all these exceptions, because i cant find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the list of possible errors produced by Firebase Auth APIs in the API documentation.  They are all subclasses of [FirebaseAuthException](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthException):

> FirebaseAuthActionCodeException, FirebaseAuthEmailException, FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException, FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException, FirebaseAuthMultiFactorException, FirebaseAuthRecentLoginRequiredException, FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException, FirebaseAuthWebException

See also:

- [How to catch a Firebase Auth specific exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37859582/807126)
- [How to handle FirebaseAuth exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40138696/807126)

Comment: Thank you! i saw the post but i wanted a kotlin code, but i think i can work with that